# How to generate the javascript files in the war directory of GWT application using Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt, command-prompt

I'm a beginner in Maven and GWT. I am working on the task which is given to me. So, there is a GWT Web Application Project just like Paint and it is developed in Eclipse. It comprises of 3 projects - A, B, and C. The project A is the main project and it is dependent on project B and C. The first thing I did was to convert all of these three projects into Maven projects in Eclipse and under the pom.xml file of the project A, I added the dependencies of the projects B and C along with several plugins and dependencies for running the GWT application in devmode.

After that, I run the following commands in the CMD after navigating to the base directory of the project: `mvn war:exploded` and `mvn gwt:devmode`. The first command created an exploded app in specified directory and I was expecting the second command to run the application in the devmode but it didn't happen. Sometimes, the second command showed some kind of errors like not finding the module.gwt.xml file and also like not able to execute the goal. At another instance, the devmode in the browser was launched but it was not showing the web application homepage but was showing the directory of the module.

I just saw the nocache.js file in the war directory but what I wanted was to generate the several javascript cache files in the war folder of my main project. How can I achieve that?

Comment: For A, B and C are client or server modules? (server means ~servlet, client means GWT), and also, to reduce confusion you should note that there are 2 maven plugins, the legacy one/mojo maven plugin, and the new generation/tbroyer plugin, which one are you using?. And, A,B,C are 3 projects or one project with 3 modules?

Comment: @IgnacioBaca, A, B and C are client modules and I am using the tbroyer plugin. A, B and C are projects. I have added the Java Build Path of B and C in A using properties.

Comment: One project with 3 modules will be much easier, at least if you need to modify the source code of B and C when developing A, alternatively you can create one more project just as a parent of the 3 other one, just to make maven reactor happy. . Also a minimal github project it much easier to help you find the best project layout.

Comment: Actually I have been given this web application made of 3 projects. I don't want to create the new projects but I want to generate the Javascript.cache files

Comment: Not sure I understand but to compile the project just execute 'mvn clean install' in C, B and finally A.

Comment: did the answer solves your problem? or it was another thing...

Comment: No, it didn't solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

To generate GWT javascript output using maven plugin you should use:

```
mvn package
```

The generated JS code should be available in the `target` folder both as a folder and as a war (it uses the `mvn` final module name, default to `{artifact}-{version}`). If your project depends on eachoder, you can use `mvn install` instead, starting from parent and installing each child progressively.

If you do not see the generated JS files in the output it is bc you have not configured the `gwt-maven-plugin` properly. Follow the instructions here (https://tbroyer.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/usage.html). You can start just checking if the maven project type is `gwt-app`.